# How to filter multiple conditions in same column pyspark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column like below:

```
+-------+------------------+-------+
|   name|             value|user_id|
+-------+------------------+-------+

| user 1|             view |      1|
| user 1|         processed|      1|
| user 2|             view |      3|
| user 3|             view |      4|
+-------+------------------+-------+
```

I want to get column like below.

```
+-------+------------------+-------+
|   name|             value|user_id|
+-------+------------------+-------+
| user 2|             view |      3|
| user 3|             view |      4|
+-------+------------------+-------+
```

simply, eliminate ids which done both action.

currently, I have two data frame like below

```
df1 = df.where(value=="processed").select("id").distinct()
df2 = df.where(value=="view").select("id").distinct()
```

now, how to get only ids which only have view not processed.Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: can you format your question please?

Comment: done... Please check now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be a `"leftanti"` self join to eliminate all `name`'s that contain `"processed"`:

```
result = df.join(df.where(df.value=="processed") \
                   .select("name") \
                   .distinct(),
                 "name", "leftanti")
result.show()
+------+-----+-------+
|  name|value|user_id|
+------+-----+-------+
|user 3| view|      4|
|user 2| view|      3|
+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: thanks mtoto. but there are multiple values in the column.  atleast 5,6 different values.

Comment: i think this should work. i will add multiple where clause